# How to return a certain set of sub-strings using SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, loops, recursion

Using MySQL, having `x = 'aa.bb.cc'`, how can I obtain the list `'aa.bb.cc', 'aa.bb', 'aa'`?

With `x = '39.01'`, the list is `'39.01', '39'`.

With `x = '39.02.01.01'`, the list is `'39.02.01.01', '39.02.01', '39.02', '39'`.

From the last example above with `x = '39.02.01.01'`, I would want to be able to construct something like:

```
SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE foo IN bar
```

where `bar` is dynamically obtained as `('39.02.01.01', '39.02.01', '39.02', '39')`.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: This seems like a misuse of MySQL… can you give us some background? What are you trying to do?

Comment: @Lübnah: I'm merely trying to see if I can keep something "in sql" to keep some requirements code-agnostic. I know my question is not so clear; tomorrow morning it'll probably be all clear to me especially with some helpful answers and comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope `INSTR` or `LOCATE` functions may work for you:

```
 SELECT * from TABLE table1 WHERE INSTR(bar, foo) = 1;
```

or

```
 SELECT * from TABLE table1 WHERE LOCATE(foo, bar) =1 ;
```

Here `bar` can be `39.02.01.01` and `foo` can be a substring e.g. `'39.02.01.01', '39.02.01', '39.02', '39'`.

Comment: that could possibly work, but would it return `'02.01.01'` if it existed?

Comment: You beat me with this solution by 2 seconds.  I had almost exactly the same response.  One difference, it should be:  WHERE (instr(bar, foo) = 1)   ---  instr() returns 0 when the foo is NOT found in bar, and 1 when bar begins with foo.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at using SUBSTRING_INDEX?

Something like this:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(field1,".",4) as One, SUBSTRING_INDEX(field1,".",3) as Two,
 SUBSTRING_INDEX(field1,".",2) as Three, SUBSTRING_INDEX(field1,".",1) as Four FROM Test
```

If your values do not all contain the same number of 'delimiters', the result may not be what you're looking for & I need at least another couple of cups of coffee to think about a solution to something like that :-)

Comment: You definitely need another cup of coffee, you used the same alias `as One` for all the columns. :)

Comment: Yep, lemme go get another one... :-)